# How to support login using sAMAccountName or any other parameter in LDAP with Apache Shiro?

Tags: java, ldap, shiro

I would like to authenticate and authorize the user with sAMAccountName with this [Realm File](https://apache.googlesource.com/isis/+/d87b77f170bdd8a9121e0058b1b67596da0c633e/component/security/shiro/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/security/shiro/IsisLdapRealm.java).

```
final NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResultEnum = ldapCtx.search(searchBase, "objectClass="+groupObjectClass, SUBTREE_SCOPE);
```

I tried the following things but it didn't work. I am trying to make this parameter (sAMAccountName) as configurable. By default its working with UserPrincipalName and name parameters.

case #1:

```
final NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResultEnum = ldapCtx.search(searchBase, "(&(objectClass=*)(sAmAccountName={0}))", SUBTREE_SCOPE);
```

case #2:

```
final NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResultEnum = ldapCtx.search(searchBase, "(&(objectClass=Person)(sAmAccountName={0}))", SUBTREE_SCOPE);
```

Do I need to configure something else also in order to support the login using sAMAccountName Parameter?

Comment: You will probably be able to use UPN. To use samAccountName, you will need to add the domainName. domainName\samaccountname.

Comment: @jeemster, how do I remove this dependency of domain\  in front of samAccountName? Note: I support multiple domains.

Comment: AFIK, you can not. How would you know which domain the user is within without specifying the domain?

Comment: @jeemster I assume that the search base contains (DC=domain, DC=com) ,wouldn't be enough? I have enabled indexing for sAMAccountName as searchable field in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

To use samAccountName, you will need to add the domainName. domainName\samaccountname.

how do I remove this dependency of domain\ in front of samAccountName? Note: I support multiple domains?
AFIK, you can not. How would you know which domain the user is within without specifying the domain

I assume that the search base contains (DC=domain, DC=com) ,wouldn't be enough?
Adding DC=domainName, DC=com should work IF you can "chase" referrals as there will be multiple contexts within the search.

Usually, depending on your setup, you could use CN=Users, DC=domainName, DC=Com and it would work without referrals.